# How to send a mock object as JSON in mockmvc

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, gson, mockito

I want to send a mock object in the controller via MockMvc with content type JSON. But when I am trying to serialize the mock the error is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Expecting parameterized type, got interface org.mockito.internal.MockitoInvocationHandler.
 Are you missing the use of TypeToken idiom?
```

My code is as following:

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){

    String xyz = "";
    Integer i = 10;
    SomeClass inst = mock(SomeClass.class, withSettings().serializable());
    when(inst.getProperty1()).then(xyz);
    when(inst.getProperty2()).then(i);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(inst); // this is creating error

    this.mockmvc.perform(put("/someUrl/").contentType(MediaType.JSON).content(json)).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: you are mocking the SomeClass can you check if gson.toJson(inst) api can handle a mocked object. i guess thats the issue here

Comment: True, but there has to be a way to serialize a mock object else there will no way of sending a mock object as a content to the controller. The only way out now is using a fake object instead of mock?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I propose that you create a [stub](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs) of your `SomeClass` that returns known values for the `getProperty1()` and `getProperty2()` method. Depending on how `SomeClass` is implemented, you could either create a `new` instance of it directly, subclass and override some methods, create an anonymous inner class if it is an interface, etc.

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){

    String xyz = "";
    Integer i = 10;

    // alt 1:
    SomeClass stub = new SomeClass(xyz, i);

    // alt 2: 
    SomeClass stub = new StubSomeClass(xyz, i); // StubSomeClass extends SomeClass

    // alt 3: 
    SomeClass stub = new SomeClass() {
         @Override
         String getProperty1() {
             return xyz;
         }
         @Override
         Integer getProperty2() {
             return i;
         }
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(stub);

    this.mockmvc.perform(put("/someUrl/")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Alt 3 is a nice way to go about. Since I was trying to mock a model (a bean) I could always use overriding getters returning things i want. But I think the stub here is itself a fake object and that i won't able to verify the behavior and calls on the object which was my main purpose.

Comment: There is no MediaType.JSON name.

Comment: @Dims Sorry, that was a copy / paste error from the original question. [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#APPLICATION_JSON) is the correct name.

Answer (score 6):

Even if it was possible, submitting a mock object to a JSON converter would suppose a unit test dedicated to that operation : the mock object may have many attributes and methods far beyond the real class and the serialization could lead to a **really strange** result.

IMHO, as it is a unit test, you should write by hand the json serialized String. And you can do other tests if you need to control how Gson does the serialization

Comment: Makes sense. BTW to do this kind of implementation does it means I should mock the GSon instance and then implement toJSon() function? Also I think what makes more sense is that via MockMvc we are trying to replicate a browser request. Since browsers mostly (rather comfortably) works with Json, which means even if I am converting the mock into json it will be stripped of all the when() and then() resulting in a plain Json with no value of mocking to it.

Comment: Downvoted since by no means a WebMVC / MockMVC is a unit tests - it is an integration test and thus needs serialization

Comment: @EugenMayer Certainly you are right. I wrote *unit* test when I really meant *a test case running in Junit*. I am sorry but my English is not good enough for me to rewrite this answer with a correct wording.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a way to serialize a mock object in a following manner:

```
Gson gson = new GSon();
String json = gson.toJson(mockedObject, mockedObjectType.class);
```

Although what I was trying was a USELESS case since json will be stripped of all the mocking i have provided in the test() function thereby when the object will be rebuilt it will have no value of mocking to it and will throw NullPointerException at the first instance of usage of any function/property.

EDIT : If you want to serialize nulls there is a function for that too :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue:
there was logging statement for outputting an object serialized to json. And unit test case for this produced error because gson couldn't serialize mock object.
It was solved with providing exclusion strategy that skips serializing Class and fields of type Class:

```
 private final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz instanceof Class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes field) {
        return field.getDeclaredClass() == Class.class;
    }
}).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

In test configuration you may wrap default message converter with another message converter which supports serialization of any object into String.

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MockObjectHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter {


  private final AbstractHttpMessageConverter primaryConverter;

  public MockObjectHttpMessageConverter(AbstractHttpMessageConverter primaryConverter) {
    this.primaryConverter = primaryConverter;
    setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object readInternal(Class clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  @Override
  protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    try {
      primaryConverter.write(o, MediaType.ALL, outputMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      IOUtils.write(o.toString(), outputMessage.getBody());
    }
  }
}
```

In Spring's context XML put:

```
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="com.example.MockObjectHttpMessageConverter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="gson">
                    <bean class="com.google.gson.Gson" factory-bean="gsonBuilder" factory-method="create"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
```